# What Bluetooth profile is used in OBD adapters like Automatic (https://www.automatic.com/adapter/) in case of iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, obd-ii

As far as I have seen they are using Bluetooth Serial Port Profile(SPP) for communication in Android. Which is not supported in iOS. Is it something related to MFi? Can someone please explain how it is done?

Comment: The specs say that it is dual mode - Both Bluetooth Low Energy and EDR mode and is mFI certified.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't exactly understand the dual mode itself and how it is doing the work. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Since they have mFI certification, my guess is that the use BLE to locate and connect to the device initially and then use a legacy "SPP" connection to transfer data at a higher rate than BLE allows

Comment: I get the first half of your answer. May I know only that " legacy "SPP" " part.

Comment: The Serial Port Protocol (SPP) is part of Bluetooth 2.1 - It allows faster transfer than the GATT protocol under Bluetooth 4 (Bluetooth Low Energy).  Use of SPP under iOS requires that the device is certified under the MFi program.